# Issues with Automatically setting created and modified date on each record in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, change-tracking

Using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with EF Core, I have followed various guides in trying to implement the automatic creation of date/time values when creating either a new record or editing/updating an existing one.

The current result is when i initially create a new record, the CreatedDate & UpdatedDate column will be populated with the current date/time.
However first time I edit this same record, the UpdatedDate column is then given a new date/time value (as expected) ***BUT*** for some reason, EF Core is wiping out the value of the original CreatedDate which results in SQL assigning a default value.

Required result I need as follows:

Step 1: New row created, both CreatedDate & UpdatedDate column is given a date/time value (this already works)
Step 2: When editing and saving an existing row, I want EF Core to update the UpdatedDate column with the updated date/time only, BUT leave the other CreatedDate column unmodified with the original creation date.

I'm using EF Core code first, and do no want to go down the fluent API route.

One of the guides i was partially following is https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx but neither this or other solutions I've tried is giving the result I am after.

Baseclass:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext Class:

```
 public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added || E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }

        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
```

*UPDATE FOLLOWING ADVICE FROM STEVE IN COMMENTS BELOW*

I spent a bit more time debugging today, turns out the methods I posted above are appear to be functioning as expected i.e. when editing an existing row and saving it, only the entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified IF statement is being called. So what I'm finding is that after saving the entity, the CreatedDate column is being overwitten with a Null value, I can see this by watching the SQL explorer after a refresh. I believe the issue is along the lines of what Steve mentions below "If it is #null then this might also explain the behavior in that it is not being loaded with the entity for whatever reason."

But i'm a little lost in tracing where this CreatedDate value is being dropped somewhere through edit/save process.

Image below shows the result at the point just before the entity is saved following an update. In the debugger I'm not quite sure where to find the entry of the CreatedDate to see what value is held at this step, but it appears to be missing from the debugger list so wandering whether somehow it doesn't know about the existence of this field when saving.

[image: Debugging screenshot]

Below is the method I have in my form 'Edit' Razor page model class:

```
 public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyProject.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EditModel(MyProject.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public RuleParameters RuleParameters { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        RuleParameters = await _context.RuleParameters
            .Include(r => r.SystemMapping).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

        if (RuleParameters == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
       ViewData["SystemMappingID"] = new SelectList(_context.SystemMapping, "ID", "MappingName");
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(RuleParameters).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!RuleParametersExists(RuleParameters.ID))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool RuleParametersExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.RuleParameters.Any(e => e.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Possibly one of the reasons for this issue is the fact that I have not included the CreatedDate field in my Edit Razor Page form, so when I update the entity which in turn will run the PostAsync method server side, there is no value stored for the CreatedDate field and therefore nothing in the bag by the tine the savechangesasync method is called in my DbContext Class. But I also didn't think this was necessary? otherwise I'd struggle to see what value there is in the this process of using an inherited BaseEntity class i.e. not having to manually add the CreatedDate & UpdatedDate attribute to every model class where I want to use it...

Comment: I test the doc and it works well.Have you added breakpoints to check that whether when you update the entity it still comes into `entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added`?Could you post your update code in controller?

Comment: Hi Xing, thanks for your reply, I've added some further notes to my question based on the feedback from yourself and Steve below, still investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Possibly one of the reasons for this issue is the fact that I have not included the CreatedDate field in my Edit Razor Page form, so when I update the entity which in turn will run the PostAsync method server side, there is no value stored for the CreatedDate field and therefore nothing in the bag by the tine the savechangesasync method is called in my DbContext Class.

That's true.Your post data does not contains the original `CreatedDate`,so when save to database, it is null and could not know what the exact value unless you assign it before saving.It is necessary.

You could just add below code in your razor form.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CreatedDate" />
```

Update:

To overcome it in server-side,you could assign data manually:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    RuleParameters originalData = await _context.RuleParameters.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == RuleParameters.ID);

    RuleParameters.CreatedDate = originalData.CreatedDate;

    _context.Attach(RuleParameters).State = EntityState.Modified;


    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Xing, I had considered this but wasn't too keen on using hidden fields in the form due to security, would this be the only viable solution? is it somehow possible to mange this server side so I dont require a hidden field?

Comment: @OJB1 Maybe you could retrieve the original createdData by ID of `RuleParameters` before `_context.SaveChangesAsync` using EF core firstly and then assign that existing createdDate to the posted RuleParameters.CratedData.It is a little 
a little trouble but should work...

Comment: Hi Xing/Steve, I'll give that a go, big thanks to both yourself and Steve for your help throughout this investigation.

Answer (score 4):

It may be easier to just give your `BaseEntity` a constructor:

```cs
public BaseEntity()
{
    UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    CreatedDate = CreatedDate ?? UpdatedDate;
}
```

Then you can have your `DbContext` override `SaveChangesAsync` like:

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(
    bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess,
    CancellationToken token = default)
{
    foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && x.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .Select(x => x.Entity)
        .Cast<BaseEntity>())
    {
        entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, token);
}
```

Comment: Hi, result i got from your suggestion is that when editing/saving an existing row, both the CreatedDate and UpdatedDate columns are modified with the updated time/date value. So i would need the CreatedDate column to remain unmodified with the original date/time.

Comment: @OJB1 I edited my answer with a change to the constructor that should address that issue.

Comment: Tried this but I found that both date/time columns were still being updated.

Comment: @OJB1 It sounds like the `CreatedDate` value is being set somewhere else inadvertently. Are you mapping to/from and view models? Is there a trigger on the database itself? The code in your original question should have been working. And the `SaveChangesAsync` override in my answer only ever sets `UpdatedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suspect EF is doing this, but rather your database, or you're inadvertently inserting records instead of updating them.

A simple test: Put break-points in your SaveChangesAsnc method within both the Modified and Added handlers and then run a unit test that loads an entity, edits it, and saves. Which breakpoint is hit?  If the behavior seems to be normal with a simple unit test, repeat again with your code.

If the Modified breakpoint is hit, and only the Modified handler is hit then check the state of the CreatedDate value in the entity modified. Does it still reflect the original CreatedDate?  If yes, then it would appear that something in your schema will be overwriting it on save. If no then you have a bug in your code that has caused it to update. If it is #null then this might also explain the behaviour in that it is not being loaded with the entity for whatever reason. Check that the property has not been configured as something like a Computed property.

If the Added breakpoint is hit at all, then this would point at a scenario where you're dealing with a detached entity, such as an entity that was read from a different DB Context and being associated to another entity in the current DB Context and saved as a byproduct. When a DbContext encounters an entity that was loaded and disassociated with a different DbContext, it will treat that entity as a completely new entity and insert a new record.  The biggest single culprit for this is invariably MVC code where people pass entities to/from views. Entity references are loaded in one request, serialized to the view, and then passed back on another request. Devs assume they are receiving an entity that they can just associate to a new entity and save, but the Context of this request doesn't know about that entity, and that "entity" isn't actually an entity, it is now a POCO shell of data that the serializer created. It's no different to you newing up a new class and populating fields. EF won't know the difference. The result of this is you will trip the Added condition for your entity, and after completion you will have a duplicate record. (with different PK if EF is configured to treat PKs as Identity)

So an example is an Order screen: When presenting a screen to create a new order I may have loaded the Customer and passed that to the view to display customer information and will want to associate to the new order:

```
var customer = context.Customers.Single(x => x.CustomerId == 15);
var newOrder = new Order { Customer = customer };
return View(newOrder);
```

This looks innocent enough.  When we go to save the new order after setting their details:

```
public ActionResult Save(Order newOrder)
{
   context.Orders.Add(newOrder);
   newOrder.Customer.Orders.Add(newOrder);
   context.SaveChanges();
   // ...
}
```

newOrder had a reference to Customer #14, so all looks good. We're even associating the new order to the customer's order collection. We might even want to have updated fields on the customer record to reflect a change to the Modified date. However, newOrder in this case, and *all* associated data including .Customer are plain 'ol C# objects at this point. We've added the new order to the Context, but as far as the context is concerned, the Customer referenced is *also* a new record. It will ignore the Customer ID if that is set as an Identity column and it will save a brand new Customer record (ID #15 for example) with all of the same details as Customer ID 14 and associate that to the new order. It can be subtle and easy to miss until you start querying Customers and spotting duplicate looking rows.

If you are passing entities to/from views, I'd be very wary of this gotcha. Attaching and setting modified state is one option, but that involves trusting that the data has not been tampered with. As a general rule, calls to update entities should never pass entities & attach them, but rather re-load those entities, validate row version, validate the data coming in, and only copy across fields you expect should ever be modified before saving the entity associated to the DbContext.

Hopefully that gives you a few ideas on things to check to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks for your feedback, interesting read. I've added some notes to my original question following further debugging from your reply and advice. It looks like the CreatedDate value is being dropped somewhere in the save-after-edit process and therefore overwriting the DB field with a Null value. Not sure how to debug this further yet. Thanks